# How to get lorem ipsum to instantiate on multiple lines instead of 1 in VS Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, lorem-ipsum

In VS Code if I type "lorem" and then press enter it will generate a paragraph of lorem ipsum. The only problem is that the paragraph comes out as one very long line of text as opposed to several lines in the text editor. Is there a setting I can change so that it automatically generates my lorem ipsum on multiple lines?

Comment: try this: lorem*3 .... (adding extra characters to meet minimum length for comment)

Comment: All that does is do the same thing but three times.

Comment: Then add parameter for max length: lorum80*3

Answer (score 16):

I think you have to put each lorem call into its own element, like `p*4>lorem10`.

`lorem10` would be 10 words of lorem.

[image: lorem 10 emmet demo]

Comment: I saw somebody do it on YouTube without explanation which is why I thought it was possible in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Go to settings and type in "word wrap". Change "Editor: Word Wrap" from "off" to "bounded". This does exactly what I was wanting in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can write `lorem20*5` and press the tab

20 = number of words
5 = number of lines

This will generate 20 random words in 5 lines in VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write *lorem* and the add the amount of words you would like it to add next to it like so:

```
//up to 10 words:
    
   lorem10
                
//up to "n" words:
   lorem"n"
```

as a result you would get:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, odio!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple vscode extension [lorem ipsum](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.lorem-ipsum)

Answer (score 0):

```
Open VS Code.
Go to the settings "Settings".
In the search bar at the top of the Settings tab, type "word wrap" and press Enter.
Look for the setting named "Editor: Word Wrap" and make sure it's set to "on". This setting will automatically wrap long lines in the editor.
Close the Settings tab.
```

Now, when you type Lorem Ipsum text in VS Code, it should automatically wrap onto multiple lines instead of extending off the screen horizontally.